# how to use Regular expression extractor to extract value from response in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

```
<input                                                     
 name="formToken"                  type="hidden"
 value="19225544fb878c9a8c77dafdfe616454a13e3c96"
/>
```

above is the line having lot of space in between. i want to extract value using regular expression in Jmeter. so please help me for regular expression to extract.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a find on this regex:

```
value="([^"]+)"
```

And then access the following in the template:

```
$1$
```

See the demo link below for an example of this working.

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Be informed that [using Regular Expression Extractor for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), I would recommend going for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) instead, the relevant configuration would be as simple as:

- Selector: `input[name=formToken]`
- Attribute: `value`

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: I've read of performance considerations when using CSS Extractor, do you reckon the impact is negligible?

Comment: Try copying your response data into a [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide/), set connect time, latency and response time to 0 and perform 2 tests, one with Regular Expression Extractor and another one with CSS Selector Extractor. Compare the throughput/number of samples using [Summary Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) listener or equivalent. The one which have more throughput will have better performance.

Comment: Thanks for the above @dmitri. Will give this a short and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following Regex:

value="(.+?)"